# Taking derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This is my code:

```
X := g[P]
P = a*t 
R = t*X

FOC = Dt[R, t]
```

This is what I get for the last line:

> ```
> g[at] + t(a + t Dt[a,t]) g'[at]
> ```

This is what I would like to get for the last line:

> ```
> X + t a (dX/dP)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x := X[P]
P = a*t
R = t*x
FOC = Dt[R, t, Constants -> a]

(* X[a t] + a t X'[a t] *)
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps try the following:

```
P = a*t
R = t*g[P]
Format[g[x_]] = X
Format[g'[x_]] = dX/dP
FOC = Dt[R, t, Constants -> {a}]
```

Comment: Perfect...Thanks!